# Not smooth rotation of UIWebView embedded Youtube video

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-api

Im using the Youtube iOS helper library to play a YT video inline in my app. My app generally works smoothly, and the videos load and play fine. I had an issue in which when I rotated the phone (simulator), the video would leave the frame. So if I loaded the video in portrait, the video would be centered in portrait, but when I rotated to landscape the video would be in the bottom corner.

To solve this issue, I now resize the player with some javascript.

```
- (void)setSizeOfIFrameToWidth:(int)width Height:(int)height {
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player.setSize(%d, %d)", width, height]];
}
```

(Thats inside the YTPlayer class that I edited).

This works fine and gets called in the youtubeView's owner:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [self.youtubeView setSizeOfIFrameToWidth:self.youtubeView.frame.size.width Height:self.youtubeView.frame.size.height];
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self.youtubeView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

(I'm not sure if that last `setNeedsDisplay` line does anything)

But now, when it rotates, first the view gets cut off on the side, and then rotates awkwardly. It looks very choppy. Here's the best screenshots I can get:

[image][image][image]

And also

[image][image][image]

Notice how during rotation the video gets cut.

(For the record, I don't own the rights to the video in the player. That's from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q78COTwT7nE)

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(window).trigger('resize');` should help.